# How do I add a dot after section number in the header with fancyhdr?

Tags: numbering, fancyhdr, titlesec

I am having a hard time trying to add a dot after section number in the header, the package I am using is `fancyhdr`.

I tried the following which did not work

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markleft{\thesection. #1}}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\scriptsize \slshape \nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{lipsum}

\lipsum

\section{lipsum}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Also, it would be preferred if this could be done without defining new command.

Thank you in advance!

---

Update, there is one minor question, which is, if you use the following code

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[UTF8, english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[a4paper, left = 27 mm, right = 27 mm, top = 27 mm, bottom = 23 mm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% >>>>>>>>>>>>> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ footnote & hyperlink ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <<<<<<<<<<<<< %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage[colorlinks = false, pdfborderstyle ={/S/D}]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% >>>>>>>>>>>>> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ footnote & hyperlink ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <<<<<<<<<<<<< %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}{
\headrule
\sethead[\footnotesize \slshape \thesection. \textsc{\sectiontitle}][][]{}{}{\footnotesize \slshape \thesection. \textsc{\sectiontitle}}
}

\titleformat{\section}[frame]{\usefont{OT1}{lmdh}{m}{it}}{\thesection}{\baselineskip}{\filcenter}[]

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\usefont{OT1}{qpl}{m}{bf}}{\thesubsection.}{\tabcolsep}{\filcenter}[]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{main}

\section{this section}

\lipsum

\section{that section}

\

\lipsum

I will cite \cite{lamport94}.

\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The header for the reference section would follow the numbering of previous section, which is shown below

[image: reference numbering in header]

However, it is clear that reference section is not numbered. I currently have a solution where you just set the pagestyle to be `plain` for the reference. Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to do with `titleps` (a companion package of `titlesec`). I took the liberty to change the header fontsize from \scriptsize to \footnotesize (I think the former is really hard to read):

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\headrule
\sethead[\footnotesize \slshape \MakeTextLowercase{\thesection. \sectiontitle}][][]{}{}{\footnotesize \slshape \MakeTextLowercase{\thesection. \sectiontitle}
}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\section{Lipsum}

\lipsum

\section{Lipsum}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this does worked for me, however, there is one minor point I would like to ask. Doing this would cause the reference section being numbered in the header, the number is, of course, the same as the last section. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @zyy: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem. Are referring to what happens for unnumbered sections, or something else?

Comment: I am sorry I did not make it clear. The problem is, there is no numbering for the section reference where you have a section of references listed, however, its name shown in the header has a number with it. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: Could you please post a full, yet minimal, code showing the problem, that we can play with?

Comment: Did you mean posting another question?

Comment: @zyy: Not necessarily, just editing you question for an addendum.

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you so much!